# linking clapack on linux

Tags: linux, static-linking, lapack

I am moving a project which uses clapack from osx to linux and experiencing some problems with it.  I use clapack by downloading the cmake project, compiling and moving the necessary .h and .a files to a relevant location within my project.

I have used the same steps in both scenarios (osx and linux) and have the same exact source code on both machines however I cannot get the everything to link properly on linux.

the lined of code in my cmake file look like this

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# INCLUDE CLAPACK
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${VMT_PRJ_SOURCE_DIR}/CLAPACK)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${VMT_PRJ_SOURCE_DIR}/CLAPACK/lib)
LINK_LIBRARIES(blas f2c lapack tmglib)
```

and the error I am getting looks like this

```
/CLAPACK/lib/liblapack.a(sgesvd.c.o): In function `sgesvd_':
sgesvd.c:(.text+0x456): undefined reference to `s_cat'
sgesvd.c:(.text+0x1fa4): undefined reference to `s_cat'
```

This is the first time I have done a port from osx to linux and don't know if there are some different requirements I need to make in order to link or what the problem is

Any help would be much appreciated.

Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of linking matters. Since `liblapack.a` needs functions from `libf2c.a`, the latter needs to come after the former. So changing

```
LINK_LIBRARIES(blas f2c lapack tmglib)
```

to

```
LINK_LIBRARIES(blas lapack f2c tmglib)
```

should help.

Comment: That has helped with some of the errors but there are still some undefined references.

Why is this a problem with the gcc compiler on linux but not osx?

Comment: I don't really know about the linker OS X uses. Possibly it's more intelligent. The thing to keep in mind under Linux is just to put each library *after* all libraries that use it, then it should work just fine.